# Flutter Error: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Game>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build an app with different lists of games. As a backend I use Firebase and the connection is working fine, I tested it. Anyway I have problems with replacing the mock data with real data from firebase. I always get this error:

> type 'Future < dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List < Game>'

I have following function:

```
getGames() async{
 List newGamesList = [];

  QuerySnapshot result = awaitFirestore.instance.collection('products').getDocuments();
  List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
  documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  Game game = new Game.fromDocument(doc);
  newGamesList.add(game);

});
}
```

"Game" looks like that:

```
factory Game.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot document) {

return new Game(
  name: document['name'],
  box: document['box'],
  cover: document['cover'],
  description: document['description'],

);
}
```

In my build widget I call "getGames":

```
new HorizontalGameController(getGames()),
```

Any idea why this error occures and how to solve that?

**EDIT:**

For better understanding here is my HorizontalGameController:

```
class HorizontalGameController extends StatelessWidget {
HorizontalGameController(this.gameItems);
final List<Game> gameItems;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new SizedBox.fromSize(
  size: const Size.fromHeight(240.0),
  child: new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 1,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, top: 4.0),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
        return GameContainerItem(context, gameItems[position]);
      }),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

getGames is not returning the gameList you created. Make the function return the list of games. I can't test it, but give this a try

```
Future<List<Game>> getGames() async{
 List<Game> newGamesList = [];

  QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance.collection('products').getDocuments();
  List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
  documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  Game game = new Game.fromDocument(doc);
  newGamesList.add(game);

});

return newGamesList;
}

//then this
//new HorizontalGameController(await getGames()) //change this
```

**EDIT**
   Change `new HorizontalGameController(await getGames())` to the code below (wrap it with a futureBuilder). This will enable the widget make use of the future value.

```
FutureBuilder<List<Game>>(
                            future: getGames(),
                            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Game>> gamelistSnapshot){
                                  return (gamelistSnapshot.hasData)? HorizontalGameController(gamelistSnapshot.data) : Container();
                            },
                        )
```

Comment: new HorizontalGameController(getGames()) gives me this error: "The argument type Future <List<Game>> cant be assigned to the parameter type List<Game>. Anyway thanks for your response!

Comment: look at the last part of the code .. change that line to `new HorizontalGameController(await getGames())` --- take note of the `await` keyword

Comment: I tried it with await, but the IDE just marks it as "Unexpected text await". Do I need to set something in my build Widget async?

Comment: Thank you! All the errors are gone now. But my list seems to be empty... Can you tell me why "print(documents.length" inside the getGames method does not print to the console? There is no output.

Comment: I can't tell. Make sure products collections exists and contains data in it. Make sure your internet connection is okay and try restarting/re-installing the app

Comment: Mhh ok, I tried reinstalling and restarting, but "print(gamelistSnapshot.data)" still results in Null... Thank you anyway!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191448/discussion-between-nonybrighto-and-martin-seubert).